# Correct use of `= delete` for methods in classes

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Is the following snipplet correct for un-defining all otherwise generated methods and constructors for a class?

```
struct Picture {

  // 'explicit': no accidental cast from string to Picture
  explicit Picture(const string &filename) { /* load image from file */ }

  // no accidental construction, i.e. temporaries and the like
  Picture() = delete;

  // no copy
  Picture(const Picture&) = delete;

  // no assign
  Picture& operator=(const Picture&) = delete;

  // no move
  Picture(Picture&&) = delete;

  // no move-assign
  Picture& operator=(Picture&&) = delete; // return type correct?
};
```

This deletes every default compiler implementation and only leaves the destructor, right? Without it the class would be (almost) unusable I guess, but I could delete it as well, correct?

Is the return type `Picture&` of the move-assign `operator=(Picture&&)` correct? Does it make a difference if I wrote `Picture&&` for the return type?

Comment: It seems like C++ has really changed a lot in C++0x!, Interesting stuff.

Comment: it's a clearer syntax then the common practice of hiding those methods in a `private` section, and only *declaring* but not *defining* them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to Xeo's answer:

Yes, everything is correct.  If you wanted you could eliminate all of the deleted members but the deleted copy constructor and deleted copy assignment and have the same effect:

```
struct Picture {  // Also ok

  // 'explicit': no accidental cast from string to Picture
  explicit Picture(const string &filename) { /* load image from file */ }

  // no copy
  Picture(const Picture&) = delete;

  // no assign
  Picture& operator=(const Picture&) = delete;
};
```

The explicit declaration of the copy constructor inhibits the implicit generation of the default constructor, move constructor and move assignment members.  Having these members explicitly deleted is a matter of taste.  Some will probably see it as good documentation.  Others may see it as overly verbose.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that in the draft text. That saves typing time. I assume I could `= default` them if I wanted them in?

Comment: Yes.  You can explicitly default them or explicitly delete them.

Answer (score 3):

Seems fine to me. The return value of `operator=` **must** be a normal reference, even if the object is constructed from a rvalue reference. That is because you can't just compile an lvalue (`*this`) to an rvalue.
And it should take that rvalue reference per non-const `Picture& operator=(Picture&&)`. How would you move from a constant object? ;)

Comment: Of course, how silly of me. You are right on both accounts. Let me correct it in the question, so the readers do not learn from my faulty example.